# How to set variable of command output with spaces as one string?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, escaping

I'm sorry in advance that the question may be confusing.

I'm working with a command-line interface of a remote program, `fw` that manages medical images.  The program has their own documentation of commands that are similar in manner to bash commands (`ls` in this example, in line 3 of my `for` loop).

`IDs` is an array of scan IDs, which I use to access the paths within the program, `fw`, with the previously mentioned `ls` command. The `echo` line is just for my testing purposes. I would like to add each `$line` to an array called `ls`. Problem is, spacing in the output with back `` from `fw ls` has spaces, and I'm trying to make it one string, since `echo ${#ls[@]}` gives me a much larger number than what the true number of scans are (843 vs 3 for this example, 843 is from my actual debugging). The true number of what I'm working with is 67 scans to `ls` instead of 3, but I only included three 'fake' outputs of `line` to show you what the output looks like.

***Debugging:***

```
>>> echo ${line[@]}

admin Dec 3 15:37 2010-12-03 16:02:11
admin Mar 6 09:23 2014-03-06 09:31:16
admin Jul 23 11:12 2016-07-23 11:26:10

>>> echo ${#ls[@]}
843

### I should be getting 
>>> echo ${#ls[@]}
3
```

**How do I modify my line for appending to `ls` in my `for` loop?**

```
for idx in ${IDs[@]}
do
   line=`fw ls "myuniversity/test/${IDs[$idx]}/"`
   echo $line
   ls+=("$line")
done
```

Comment: `idx` is the value you want, not an index into `IDs`. `line=$(fw ls "myuniversity/test/$idx")`.

Comment: You are capturing the values just fine. Your error is failing to quote the arguments to `echo`. This is a very common FAQ.

Comment: You should also quote `"${IDs[@]}"`. The line `ls+=("$line")` should be fine.

Comment: @tripleee `echo $line` doesn't explain the claimed output of `echo ${#ls[@]}`, though.

Comment: We can only speculate that they are doing something like `ls=($(command))` and expecting he result to be an array of lines, but getting an array of tokens. There is also no way the output could be split across three lines like that if they `echo` the value without quotes.

Comment: Speculate? It's in the question: `ls+=$("line")`. I agree the question needs some work, but closing this as a duplicate is premature.